# How to modify value on DOM button?

Tags: angularjs

How to modify text on one specific DOM object? Tried the following code but ended up changing for all the DOM text. It changes all the {{content}} values not only 'b1'.

```
myfunc () {
  $scope.content="nothing";
  angular.element(document.getElementById('b1')).scope().content ='something';
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<button id="b1" type="button" ng-click="myfunc($event)">
    {{content}}
</button>
<button id="b2" type="button" ng-click="myfunc($event)">
    {{content}}
</button>
```

Comment: BTW, $scope.content is actually out of the function box, so ignore that line. The problem is that the above method couldn't apply to that specific DOM ID ('b1') after click, it applies to all the $scope and made changes to all the buttons ('b1' and 'b2') to display 'something'. I don't want 'b2' to change, only stays at 'nothing'.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `angular.element` or do any DOM manipulation whatsoever anywhere else than in directives. What you want to do here is define `$scope.contents` as an array / object and then update only the index you want:

```
$scope.contents = Array(2).fill('nothing');

$scope.updateButton = function(index) {
  $scope.contents[index] = 'something';
};
```

As for your template:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="updateButton(0)">{{ contents[0] }}</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="updateButton(1)">{{ contents[1] }}</button>
```

Comment: I couldn't implement this solution because my array size is not fixed. The number of buttons changes on the fly. Therefore, I couldn't pre-define it in my controller. And, there is no way of defining contents[i] array since index "i" is not in sequence. All I can manipulate is the button ID, which represent different button DOM.

Comment: This is a good solution, thank you! The only drawback is that I had to define a relatively big array size initially.